# Unordered Pairs (pair sets) in Python from a list

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a list of items

```
 alist = ['dog', 'cat', 'fish']
```

I want to return all unique unordered pairs, so in this case:

```
 (dog,cat)(dog,fish)(fish,cat)
```

`itertools.combinations` does not take into account the unordered condition, so it is not quite what I need.

Comment: What do you mean `itertools.combinations` doesn't take into account the unordered condition?

Comment: What do you mean by *unordered*? what's the logic behind it?

Comment: Do you mean you want the stuff to be a list of sets instead of a list of tuples?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Where is your problem with **itertools**?

```
import itertools

alist = ['dog', 'cat', 'fish']
for result in itertools.combinations(alist, 2):
    print result
```

output:

```
('dog', 'cat')
('dog', 'fish')
('cat', 'fish')
```

Comment: I didn't feed it the length parameter. apologies.

Comment: Then it should toss a TypeError, not give you different output.  No?